Why does pytorch gloo still send traffic from other TCP ports even though I specified the network port?
each my cpu server  have 8 TCP port, I use code as followed
if __name__ == "__main__":

   if args.local_rank % 8 == 0:
          os.environ['GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME']='br0'
   else:
       os.environ['GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME']=f'eth{args.local_rank % 8}'

   dist.init_process_group(backend='gloo', init_method='env://')
...

dist.all_reduce(data_cpu, group=data_parallel_group,async_op=False)



every local rank I tried specifiy LOO_SOCKET_IFNAME = eth{rank}, it doesn't work, there is still half workers choose eth0
